# How to convert date to numeric calendar date in Java?

Tags: java, date

Wanted to convert the following dates format:

```
Mar 10th 2016
Mar 1st 2016
Mar 2nd 2016
Mar 3rd 2016
Mar 22nd 2016
```

into

```
10-03-2016
01-03-2016
02-03-2016
03-03-2016
22-03-2016
```

Tried couple of things but failed to get the desired output.

Comment: Which things did you try?

Comment: For converting dates you should take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This question was also discussed at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: @mnille there are no pattern for ordinals like `10th` or `2nd`

Comment: You should write your own convertor for 'Mar 10th 2016' date format. It's not common

Comment: @SashaSalauyou whoa, right, so just ignore my comment :-/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I can split the date and add ordinals just wanted to know, any simple solution is available

Answer (score 0):

Try string manipulation. Read the input, split based on space and write a logic for your own converter

Answer (score 0):

As there is no pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` for ordinal day numbers, you first should clean the string, then parse the date and stringify it back using two `SimpleDateFormat`s:

```
static final DateFormat DF_FROM = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
static final DateFormat DF_TO   = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

synchronized static String convert(String date) throws ParseException {
    date = date.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(st|nd|rd|th)", ""); // remove ordinal suffix
    return DF_TO.format(DF_FROM.parse(date));            // convert
}
```

Please note usage of `synchronized` for method as `SimpleDateFormat` methods are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
private String converter (String in) throws Exception {

    String stringMonth = in.split(" ")[0];
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(stringMonth);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int  day = Integer.valueOf(in.split(" ")[1].replaceAll("[a-z]", ""));
    int year = Integer.valueOf(in.split(" ")[2]) - 1900;

    Date result = new Date();
    result.setYear(year);
    result.setMonth(month);
    result.setDate(day);

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(result);
    return dt.toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```